# Google Apps Script to delete rows from two different spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I've done a lengthy search and couldn't find what I'm looking for. Maybe someone out there can kindly help?

I have two Google Spreadsheets, Spread1 and Spread2. I will only be referring to sheet1 of both spreadsheets.

I need a script that deletes rows containing "Hello" in column B of Spread1 but only if "Hello" appears in column B of Spread2.

If rows are deleted (if the same word appears in both columns), then I would like the script to go back to Spread2 and also delete the rows with "Hello" in column B.

So after the script has run, "Hello" will not appear in column B in either of the spreadsheets.

If anyone knows how to achieve this I will be very grateful indeed - your valuable help will be much appreciated.

Thanks for looking!

EDIT:

I have this script which deletes rows in Spread2 that contain "hello" in column B:

```
function deleteRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET KEY"); 
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change to your own
  var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  for( var row = values.length -1; row >= 0; --row )
     if (values[row][1] == 'Hello')
      s.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);
};
```

but I only want it to do so when "Hello" appears in column B of Spread1. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What part of the script are you having problems with? - show code. All you describe  is easily delivered using spreadsheet services https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet

Comment: Well I have this script which deletes rows in Spread2 that contain "hello" in column B:

Comment: Well I have this script which deletes rows in Spread2 that contain "hello" in column B: 

    
    function deleteRow() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET KEY"); 
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
      var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change to your own
      var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();
      for( var row = values.length -1; row >= 0; --row )
         if (values[row][3] == 'Need today')
          s.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);
    };
but I only want it to do so when "Hello" appears in column B of Spread1. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify this solution, I'm using the [2D Array Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library), for `ArrayLib.find()`. You could instead write a function that loops through rows in sheet2 to find 'Hello'.

```
function deleteRow() {
  // This assumes script is independent of either sheet
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET KEY1").getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET KEY2").getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 

  var values1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values2 = s2.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Check if "Hello" appears in column B of Spread2.
  if (ArrayLib.find(values2, 1, 'Hello') != -1) {
    // Yes it does, so delete rows containing "Hello" in column B of Spread1
    for( var row = values.length -1; row >= 0; --row )
       if (values1[row][1] == 'Hello')
        s1.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);
    }
  }
}
```

You can further optimize this by removing the call to `deleteRow()`, modifying Spread1 in array form, then calling `clearContent()` and `setValues()` to write the modified array back to the sheet. This way, you replace `n` service calls with 2, and save lots of run time.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to both spreadsheets in the same script and process the two arrays in step

```
function deleteRow() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET KEY"); 
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
      var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change to your own
      var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();
      var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET KEY1"); 
      var s1 = ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
      var values1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
            // assumes sheets have same number of rows and you wish to delete corresponding rows in each
      for( var row = values.length -1; row >= 0; --row )
         if (values[row][1] == 'Hello' || values1[row][1] == 'Hello')
          s.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);  // parseInt is not required
          s1.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);
    };
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much for your response. I'm afraid my spreadsheets wont have the same number of rows and it's not the corresponding rows that i would like to delete. Spread1 may contain multiple rows with 'Hello' (in column B) which I'd like to delete if 'Hello' is in any of the rows in spread 2 (column B). Any ideas how I this is achieved? Many thanks